# Android - How to define value by call seekbar method?

Tags: android, view, draw, seekbar

I'm trying to set a value by calling the method from seekbar.

I call the method getProgress() and it crashes the app.

I'm doing it in a activity that extends View.

The seekbar values are set on the MainActivity.

```
public class Draw extends View 
{
    public Draw(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
    }

    Paint prop = new Paint();
    Random color = new Random();

    SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbContrast);
    int value = bar.getProgress();// it crashes here

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();

        int oriwidth = 0;
        int oriheight = 0;      

        for (int x = 0; x < 20; x++) 
        {
            int red = color.nextInt(value);
            int green = color.nextInt(value);
            int blue = color.nextInt(value);

            prop.setARGB(255, red, green, blue);
            canvas.drawRect(oriwidth += 10, oriheight += 10, width -= 10, height -= 10, prop);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help? Thanks, and sorry for the english.

Comment: you seekbar is not initialized. post the stack trace you are probably getting NPE

Comment: @Raghunandan Sorry, but how can I initialize the seekbar?

Comment: post your stack trace.

Comment: for accessing `SeekBar` from Draw class you will need to use Activity Context or pass `SeekBar` instance to Draw class using class Constructor

Comment: @Raghunandan How can I do that?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Can you explain better? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbContrast);
```

> This will return null when you try to reference it into View.

Rather you should take following approach.

move below statements to your Activity.

```
SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbContrast);
int value = bar.getProgress();
```

Create a method into your view class.

```
public void setSeekBarValue(long seekBarValue)
{
   this.seekBarValue=seekBarValue;
}
```

And from MainActivity whenever you want to pass the values to view write following snippet.

```
SeekBar bar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.skbContrast);
int value = bar.getProgress();
viewObject.setSeekBarValue(value);
```

This is not the fullproof solution just an idea to help you get started.